# How do I prevent windows from maximizing when "touching" the menu bar in Ventura?

Tags: window-manager, ui, ventura, macos

After upgrading to Ventura, everytime I drag a window up towards the menu bar, it maximizes. How do I disable that?

Comment: Sounds like you've installed some third-party window management software, like Magnet, BetterSnapTool, Moom, Rectangle.... etc...

Comment: I don't think so, this started to happen when I upgraded to Ventura. My other two machines, that  still are on Monterey don't show this behaviour, although they are very similar when it comes to their setup. Weird.

Comment: @benwiggy You were absolutely right, when I upgrade Spectacles stopped working and I had to replace it with a fork, Rectangle, and the latter had a default setting that caused this behaviour.

Comment: @benwiggy You should write this as an answer so d-b can mark it resolved

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a feature of the BetterTouchTool app. I had the same issue, and it stopped happening when I disabled BetterTouchTool. It does seem to be specific to BTT in MacOS 13 Ventura.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a built-in behaviour of macOS, so it sounds like you have installed some other window-management utility.